# Automatization of the cost calculation process

Tags: python, beginner

I am beginner in programming and I did the task "manually" by logically creating the sum of costs for each route. But I wanted to ask if it is possible to automatic (dynamic) counting of costs for a given route?

```py
original_route = [0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
route_2 = [0, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0]
route_3 = [0, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 0]

distance_matrix = [[0, 6, 12, 11, 6, 13, 8, 20, 7],
                   [6, 0, 7, 9, 7, 9, 12, 15, 13],
                   [12, 7, 0, 13, 10, 11, 16, 13, 19],
                   [11, 9, 13, 0, 15, 4, 19, 12, 14],
                   [6, 7, 10, 15, 0, 16, 6, 21, 12],
                   [13, 9, 11, 4, 16, 0, 21, 8, 18],
                   [8, 12, 16, 19, 6, 21, 0, 27, 10],
                   [20, 15, 13, 12, 21, 8, 27, 0, 26],
                   [7, 13, 19, 14, 12, 18, 10, 26, 0]]

cost_route = distance_matrix[0][4] + distance_matrix[4][2] + distance_matrix[2][1] + distance_matrix[1][3] + distance_matrix[3][0] 
print("The cost of the original route: " + str(cost_route))

cost_route2 = distance_matrix[0][3] + distance_matrix[3][5] + distance_matrix[5][2] + distance_matrix[2][4] + distance_matrix[4][6] + distance_matrix[6][0]
print("The cost of route 2: " + str(cost_route2))

cost_route3 = distance_matrix[0][7] + distance_matrix[7][6] + distance_matrix[6][4] + distance_matrix[4][1] + distance_matrix[1][5] + distance_matrix[5][0]
print("The cost of route 3: " + str(cost_route3))

value = ['1, ' + str(cost_route), '2, ' + str(cost_route2), '3, ' + str(cost_route3)]

print('Best value has route ' + str(min(value)) + ' is the value.')
print('Worst value has route ' + str(max(value)) + ' is the value.')
```

Comment: You're basically asking for a major rewrite of the code. That's not something we do here, please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @greybeard not everyone have to speak English....

Comment: (Not the least reason I don't feel called to iron out everything I feel wrong in a post I edit is English (most obviously) not being my first language. I just wanted to give a reason why I stop halfways (e.g., not supplying a pronoun in the first four words). (At least as long as edits are reviewed,) The guideline is *notably* less mistakable/more readable.)

Answer (score 1):

The general trick to "automating" code where you have multiple values that all work the same way is to:

1. Put them in a collection, like a list or a dict.
2. Take whatever you're doing to all those values and define it as a function.

In the case of this code, rather than having three variables for your routes, you should put them in a collection you can iterate over, and rather than having three copy and pasted expressions that translate the routes into costs, write a function that takes a route and calculates the cost.  This greatly reduces the risk that you'll end up with a bug because you copied+pasted something incorrectly, or forgot to update one piece of data in two different places (e.g. the values of the routes, which are currently duplicated in a sort of non-obvious way).

I don't actually understand what your code represents, but the pattern is easy enough to spot that I was able to write a script that at least produces roughly the same output while avoiding the copy+paste pitfalls.

```
from typing import List

routes = {
    '1': [0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0],
    '2': [0, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 0],
    '3': [0, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 0],
}

distance_matrix = [
    [0, 6, 12, 11, 6, 13, 8, 20, 7],
    [6, 0, 7, 9, 7, 9, 12, 15, 13],
    [12, 7, 0, 13, 10, 11, 16, 13, 19],
    [11, 9, 13, 0, 15, 4, 19, 12, 14],
    [6, 7, 10, 15, 0, 16, 6, 21, 12],
    [13, 9, 11, 4, 16, 0, 21, 8, 18],
    [8, 12, 16, 19, 6, 21, 0, 27, 10],
    [20, 15, 13, 12, 21, 8, 27, 0, 26],
    [7, 13, 19, 14, 12, 18, 10, 26, 0]
]


def cost_for_route(route: List[int], distance_matrix: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    route_shifted = route[1:] + route[0:0]
    return sum(distance_matrix[i][j] for i, j in zip(route, route_shifted))


route_costs = {
    name: cost_for_route(route, distance_matrix)
    for name, route in routes.items()
}

for name, cost in route_costs.items():
    print(f"The cost of route {name}: {cost}")

best = min(route_costs.keys(), key=route_costs.get)
worst = max(route_costs.keys(), key=route_costs.get)
print(f"Best value has route {best}, {route_costs[best]} is the value.")
print(f"Worst value has route {worst}, {route_costs[worst]} is the value.")
```

Now that `routes` is simply a dict that the rest of the code iterates through, you can add more routes just by adding them to that dict; you don't need to manually generate the code to calculate the cost of the new route, or update the code that finds the best/worst routes or the code that prints them all out.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a good explanation and help! I really appreciate, this is my first steps in programming in Uni and because of the lack of lectures we have to learn how to create programs ourselves.